# Xcode 8.0 Beta 3 vs. Xcode 8.0

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, xcode8-beta3

I am not sure what the difference is between the Xcode 8.0 Beta 3 I have been using and the regular Xcode 8.0 that is now available to download but I have been running fine in the Beta but if I open my project in the regular version I get like 50 errors. I tells me to remove the () after all UIColors and a lot more stuff that was fine in the beta?

Does anyone know if this is normal? To me it seems easier to just keep using the beta.

Comment: The release notes for Xcode 8 beta 3 indicate that it has a beta version of Swift 3.

Comment: You have to check release notes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal.

There were many changes in the Swift APIs during the beta (testing) phase.

Throw away the beta and use only the final release.